Caddy Container overwriting files in the Frontend Container
I have a docker compose file with 4 containers. Caddy , Watchtower and Frontend and Backend Container. The front end is in React + vite. The backend is Node.js and Express.
I have a shared volume between the caddy container and frontend container. The frontend is supposed to build its files using 'npm run build' then the build files should be in caddy's usr/share/caddy so they can be served.
this is my docker compose:
services:
  caddy:
    image: caddy
    container_name: caddy_container
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./Caddyfile:/etc/caddy/Caddyfile
      - caddy_data:/data
      - frontend_build:/usr/share/caddy  
    restart: always
    networks:
      - default

  backend:
    image: hashirayaz/rehaish_backend:latest
    container_name: backend_container
    # build: ./rehaish_backend
    environment:
    - MONGO_USERNAME=${MONGO_USERNAME}
    - MONGO_PASSWORD=${MONGO_PASSWORD}
    - MONGO_DATABASE=${MONGO_DATABASE}
    - PORT=${PORT}
    - JWT_SECRET=${JWT_SECRET}
    - JWT_EXPIRES_IN=${JWT_EXPIRES_IN}
    - NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}
    - CORS_ORIGIN=${CORS_ORIGIN}
    - NODE_ENV=production
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - default
    
  frontend:
    image: hashirayaz/rehaish_frontend:latest
    container_name: frontend_container
    # build: ./rehaish_frontend
    volumes:
      - frontend_build:/app/dist
    environment:
      - VITE_BACKEND_URL=${VITE_BACKEND_URL}
    networks:
      - default
    depends_on:
      - backend
      - caddy
    labels:
      - com.centurylinklabs.watchtower.enable=true

  watchtower:
    image: containrrr/watchtower
    container_name: watchtower
    restart: always
    privileged: true
    networks:
      - default
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    command: --interval 5
    environment:
      - REPO_USER=${DOCKER_USER}
      - REPO_PASS=${DOCKER_PAT}
      - WATCHTOWER_RETAIN=1

volumes:
  caddy_data:
  frontend_build:

networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge


This is my caddyfile:
{
    email hashirayaz@gmail.com
}

rehaishkikhwaish.site {
    # Serve static files from the dist folder (mounted in /usr/share/caddy)
    root * /usr/share/caddy
    encode gzip
    file_server
    
    # Reverse proxy for backend API
    handle /api/* {
        reverse_proxy backend_container:3000
    }
    handle /img/* {
        reverse_proxy backend_container:3000
    }


    tls {
        issuer acme
    }
}


When i run docker compose up, caddy's own index.html is being served on my site. When i attach shell to frontend container and cd into /app/dist, the index.html is caddy's own index.html instead of my site's index.html

The caddy image is started before the frontend  finishes

@OneCricketeer how do i fix this then

You could try adding a healthcheck to the frontend container. Then caddy depends on it... Otherwise, you should run it first to populate the volume, rather than have it start with every other service

That behavior sounds like it's consistent with Docker's rules for initializing named volumes.  There are several significant problems with trying to use named volumes to publish files from one container to another, and I'd avoid doing this.  More generally, I'd recommend never mounting anything over a directory that already contains content in the image.
You can build a Dockerfile FROM any other image you want.  Since you've already given your image an image: name, you can COPY the files in a Dockerfile from the frontend image into the proxy image; it can be as little as
# Dockerfile.caddy
FROM caddy
COPY --from=hashirayaz/rehaish_frontend:latest /app/dist /usr/share/caddy

Compose isn't aware of this build dependency between images, so you when you need to rebuild this, you need to do it in two steps
docker-compose build frontend
docker-compose build

With this setup, you'd also delete the frontend_build volume and every mention of it from the Compose file.
(It looks like nothing ever passes requests on to the frontend container.  If that only builds a frontend into static files, consider doing it in a multi-stage build.  That would let you delete the no-op container from the running application, and just running docker-compose build once would rebuild everything.)

With the setup you have here, there are two immediate technical problems you're running into.  If you start a container with a mounted Docker named volume, the volume is empty, and you mount it over a directory that has image content, then Docker copies the image content into the volume; and then, no matter what, the volume content hides what was in the original image.
If the Caddy container starts first (you force this via depends_on:) then

The Caddy container starts; the frontend_build volume is empty; you're mounting it over a directory with a skeleton index.html file; so the file is copied into the volume.
The frontend container starts; the frontend_build volume is not empty; so the /app/dist container in the image is replaced with the volume content.

It might happen to work in this particular case to reverse depends_on:, to force frontend to start before caddy rather than vice versa.  But there are several other problems with using named volumes this way:

It only works for Docker named volumes; not bind mounts, any kind of Kubernetes volume mount, nor any other storage.
If you update the image, the volume never gets updated, and you'll serve old content.
What's getting served depends on what's in the volume on this particular machine, so the setup isn't reproducible.

I'd avoid ever relying on the Docker named-volume initialization.  For many cases like this one, copying files in a Dockerfile will be much more reliable and not much more difficult.  It's also possible to use an entrypoint-wrapper script to copy files into some sort of shared storage at startup time, but this can add complexity (your setup doesn't obviously already have an entrypoint-wrapper script), and if you are planning on running in a clustered environment eventually, you can't necessarily get shared storage.
